# How to fix PHP Warning: file_get_contents?

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I'm getting following warning:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\test/wp-content/themes/test\images) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in ..\plugins\theme-check\main.php on line 29
```

The line 29 of main.php reads as:

```
$other[$filename] = file_get_contents( $filename );
```

Here is code related to $files:

```
$files = listdir( $theme );

$files = array_merge( listdir( $parent ), $files );

if ( $files ) {
        foreach( $files as $key => $filename ) {
            if ( substr( $filename, -4 ) == '.php' ) {
                $php[$filename] = php_strip_whitespace( $filename );
            }
            else if ( substr( $filename, -4 ) == '.css' ) {
                $css[$filename] = file_get_contents( $filename );
            }
            else {
                $other[$filename] = file_get_contents( $filename );
            }
        }

        // run the checks
        $failed = !run_themechecks($php, $css, $other);
```

As far I have understood, its the permission error. As the file can't seem to access that folder. I'm using XAMPP on Windows 7. I dont know how can i change the folder permissions on windows.

PS. Please notice the folder path in the warning, it has \ and also /.

I don't want to turn off the Warning etc., instead want to fix the warning.

Comment: Are you trying to do a file_get_contents on a folder called images or on a file inside of a folder called images?

Comment: You need to find the line that creates $filename or what is being passed to it to get contents from. This information will help in finding out where the issue resides

Comment: @James Williams I just added the code. Please have a look.

Comment: If $filename is blank, then your generated `$other['filename']` will contain JUST a directory. You cannot use `file_get_contents()` on a directory.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks. James Williams helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marc B hit it on the head. You need to add a test to check if the filename is a directory with php function is_dir($filename)

```
   if ( $files ) {
    foreach( $files as $key => $filename ) {
        if ( substr( $filename, -4 ) == '.php' ) {
            $php[$filename] = php_strip_whitespace( $filename );
        }
        else if ( substr( $filename, -4 ) == '.css' ) {
            $css[$filename] = file_get_contents( $filename );
        }
        else {
            if(!is_dir($filename)) $other[$filename] = file_get_contents( $filename );
        }
    }
```

### Edit

If you are doing something like a directory view online. You could go further and include the directories in a seperate array and sort them and list them out first. and then list the files. I have created something like this for a dynamic gallery.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this PHP function to replace the windows path: **getcwd()**.
You will need to concatenate the file names.